# Google Analytics find total session duration of all users

Tags: google-analytics

I'm digging through my Google Analytics menu and I can't seem to find a report that displays the total session duration of all users in a time period. Is this possible?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are looking for Average Session Duration, yes?

Average Session Duration is shown as a sparkline widget in Audience - Overview. You might need to scroll your browser page down to see it.

Avg Session duration is also a column in the Home screen.

If you want Total Session Duration, just multiply total visits by Avg Session Duration.